# Vaadin: How To Customize The Valo Theme

Tags: java, css, sass, vaadin

I'm new to SCSS and I'm asking myself how to customize the Valo Theme in a Vaadin application. I read the topic in the Book of Vaadin but I just cannot find an example for it.
My style structure is based on the [official Vaadin dashboard demo](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/tree/master/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/dashboard):

```
@import "../valo/valo";
@import "common";
@import "views/login";
@import "views/dashboardview";
@import "views/schedule";
@import "views/sales";
@import "views/transactions";
@import "views/reports";

// Optimize the CSS output
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, accordion);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, colorpicker);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, grid);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, popupview);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, progressbar);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, slider);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, splitpanel);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, tree);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, treetable);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, twincolselect);

// Main layout padding
$view-padding: round($v-unit-size / 1.5) !default;

// Slight adjustment to menu background-color
$valo-menu-background-color: #414B56;

@mixin dashboard {
  @include valo;
  @include dashboard-common;
  @include dashboard-login-view;
  @include dashboard-dashboard-view;
  @include dashboard-schedule-view;
  @include dashboard-sales-view;
  @include dashboard-transactions-view;
  @include dashboard-reports-view;
}
```

After compiling the SCSS I've got the styles.css file where I just customized a few entries for the Valo Menu. Example:

**Original:**

```
.mytheme .v-menubar-user-menu  > .v-menubar-menuitem img.v-icon {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;

    border-radius: 29px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 0.3em;
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}
```

**Customized:**

```
.mytheme .v-menubar-user-menu  > .v-menubar-menuitem img.v-icon {
    width: 69px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 0.3em;
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}
```

Now how (and where) can I define these rules, so the SCSS compiler takes the changes automatically? Otherwise everytime I compile the Theme my changes are lost.

Regards

Comment: Why don't you simply create a new style and add them to the component via `addStyleName()`?

Comment: I think It would be redundant, because the Valo standard would be rendered too and furthermore it wouldn't handle dependencies between styles... Or am I beeing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.creating.html) you add your own code at the end of your `mixin`.

> The actual theme should be defined as follows, as a mixin that includes the base theme.
>
> ```
> @import "../valo/valo.scss";
>
> @mixin mytheme {
>   @include valo;
>
>   /* An actual theme rule */
>   .v-button {
>     color: blue;
>   }
> }
> ```

In your case something along the lines:

```
@mixin dashboard {
  // ...
  .v-menubar-user-menu  > .v-menubar-menuitem img.v-icon {
     width: 69px;
     height: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exaclty what I was searching for! I don't know why I missed the part in the documentation... oO

Comment: I just realized that the additional theme rules defined in mytheme.scss are just attached to the styles.css. That's why the original entries are used too. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: @shinchillahh the general answer in CSS is either use a rule with the same "accuracy" at a later point of the original or add `!important`. to get rid of rules, explicitly setting them `auto` or `inherit` or the original default. this is not vaadin specific, but plain css and also hard to answer without knowing/seeing the actual problem (which goes beyond the original question). you might want to hunt those down with your browsers dom inspector.